# Android TV. Adding custom views to VerticalGridFragment

Tags: customization, android-tv

I am building an Android TV app and want to add some views to VerticalGridFragment. Is that possible and how?

I am using leanback library version 25.0.0. Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The [leanback-showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase) example provided by the leanback team has a great example on how to do this. I highly recommend you clone that repo and play around in that project.

You'll basically want to initialize an `Adapter` with a `Presenter` that knows how to present the views you'd like to display in your list. [This class](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/grid/GridExampleFragment.java) right here has a specific example of exactly what you're looking for.

In the example they use a `PresenterSelector`, but if your list is homogenous (backed by only one model), then you can pass in a single `Presenter` directly into the `Adapter` - like the `Presenter` [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards/presenters/VideoCardViewPresenter.java).

In code - first setup your grid presenter

```
VerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter(ZOOM_FACTOR);
gridPresenter.setNumberOfColumns(COLUMNS);
setGridPresenter(gridPresenter);
```

Then set your adapter on the `VerticalGridFragment`

```
PresenterSelector cardPresenterSelector = new CardPresenterSelector(getActivity());
mAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenterSelector);
setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then add models to your `Adapter`

```
private void createRows() {
    String json = Utils.inputStreamToString(getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.raw.grid_example));
    CardRow row = new Gson().fromJson(json, CardRow.class);
    mAdapter.addAll(0, row.getCards());
}
```

Comment: This is default usage. I need to add some custom views to that fragment (FastScroller). Not into VerticalGridView. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can't put any view nested under a VerticalGridView that isn't presented by the Presenter. You can use a PresenterSelector to present different types of views (which are backed by different models). But if you'd like to add something that isn't in the list, then you'll need to add the view outside of the VerticalGridView.

Comment: Please read my previous comment. I want my view outside VerticalGridView. How exactly can i do that?

Comment: Wow I apologize, I totally misunderstood the question. Okay so the VerticalGridFragment is backed by the layout file `lb_vertical_grid_fragment.xml`. This has a BrowseFrameLayout (which I believe is the the fragment's root view) and it has an outer FrameLayout. If you grab that outer FrameLayout, you could try and dynamically add views to that. `BrowseFrameLayout browseFrameLayout=(BrowseFrameLayout)getView().findViewById( R.id.grid_frame)`. The parent of that is the root view. Another option is to put the fragment inside an activity and add your `FastScroller` to the Activity.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I will give it a try