# Want to create a Custom View for Android TV

Tags: android, android-layout, customization, android-tv, leanback

I have already gone through several different available Questions related to this,
but not found very much useful.

1. [Android TV. Adding custom views to VerticalGridFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338410/android-tv-adding-custom-views-to-verticalgridfragment)

How I can customize the View Inside the RowSupportFragment or Like is there any other way to achieve the same.

[image: This is the Layout that needs to develop]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Presenter` right? I think you need to use different types same way `RecyclerView` and `Adapters` has the `itemViewType` and transform your `BaseCardView` based on some rule, it could be the position or the `type` of it. I manage to do something like this for a row with the "View All" last card:

```
// This is just a simple FrameLayout with an ImageView or a TextView...

var firstItem: Any? = null

class PortraitTitleCardPresenter(context: Context) :
    AbstractCardPresenter<BaseCardView>(context) {


    override fun onCreateView(): BaseCardView {
        val cardView = BaseCardView(context, null, R.style.BaseCard)
        cardView.isFocusable = true
        cardView.addView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_home, null))

        return cardView
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(card: Any, cardView: BaseCardView) {
        if(firstItem == null) {
            firstItem = card
            //Do something with firstItem...
        }

        if (card is ItemTitleType) {
            cardView.image.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            cardView.viewAll.visibility = View.GONE
            
            Glide.with(context)
                .load(card.imageUrl)
                .centerCrop()
                .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_wm_black)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                ).into(cardView.image)
        }

        if (card is ViewAllType) {
            cardView.image.visibility = View.GONE
            cardView.viewAll.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not fulfilling the Design requirement. and using the Recyclerview Adapter it is showing a very much lagging issue.

Comment: I did not mention to use RecyclerView. I did mention to use Presenter an add some behavior there to draw one tile or another based on that behavior.